# .htaccess Allow files types when logged in

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

We have a wordpress website and we want to block certain files, like .pdf and .txt when an user is not logged in and then allow the files when the user is logged in.

We know how to allow certain file types and how to check/redirect if the user is not logged in, but we don't know how to combine the two, does anyone know how to do this or if it is possible? I've listed the code we currently use in our .htaccess file at the end.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, let me know if you need any additional information.

Thank you for your time and help.

Regards

Jing Jing Tao

**Allow certain files types**

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
<files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$">
allow from all
</files>
```

**Redirect if not logged in**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

To disallow certain filetypes if not logged in...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(pdf|txt)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

I'm assuming that the two RewriteConds are correct, and both are needed. You may have to tweak them to fine tune the exact conditions that the RewriteRule will be applied under. Right now, it's looking for the term **uploads/** in the URI *AND* does **NOT** find **wordpress_logged_in** in the cookie. I presume that you are not trying to also run the "Redirect if not logged in" code.

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you for your reply. The code you have given works with in allowing access files once logged in.

Two other minor notes if you don't mind asking, 

1) We would like to add the redirect

2) How do we check if the user is logged in if we also deal with login with php sessions in a plugin, I've tried replacing "wordpress_logged_in" with "PHPSESSID", but no luck.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not a Wordpress expert, so the help I can give you is limited. For 1) is there a point in both excluding access to certain files AND redirecting the visitor if they're not logged in? I would think the file exclusion would be redundant in that case. 2) the "wordpress_logged_in" is in the _cookie_, and usually the PHP session ID isn't, but I could be wrong there. It will take a WP expert to help you with that one.

Answer (score 1):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)uploads/.+?\.(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$ wp-login.php?redirect_to=/ [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thank you for your reply, unfortunately the code you've given does not work, not sure what we're doing wrong.

Comment: This DOES seem to work. I'm guessing @anubhava didn't update the file extensions that it was checking. How would we re-direct to the requested file after they login?